Dual switch light stopped working

This is an old house (c. 1900)

The wiring looks modern but could have been installed by amateur

I think it is wire by the "alternate"  2 way method as described here

I installed a new pendant fixture following product instructions (replaced existing fixture)

At first, the fixture worked but now it doesn't

I tested the bulbs, they are fine

Continuity tests to both switches are good but I see that when a switch is relative off, I get 60-70v Com to L1 or L2 and about 80v when switched on at both volts. I don't get continuity at the sockets ( guess that's not surprising)

L2 to G is constant 120v at sockets and switches


Is this a bad live wire that I need to pull or something else? Is there something else I should test?

Are you measuring all your voltages with no load? A voltmeter is pretty much useless in many situations such as a bad connection, because they will tend to read a voltage where there isn't one.

A bit more explanation would help. Installed pendant?? Picture, showing fixture wiring would help. As for voltage measurement, often meaningless, depending on meter impedance,  capacitive coupling, etc. Most likely: miswired fixture.

Sorry it's a pendant style light fixture I don't think k that will have any relevance to the wiring though...

All readings are live and, at the switches, don't change with the bulb in or out. The only thing throwing me off is that it WAS working for a while but then stopped.

If you only did work changing wires at the fixture, then one or more of the connections at the fixture where not tighten enough, and now loose.With the breaker off, check the connections at the fixture first, then switches, then other joints/connections in the circuit.  Newer code requires the use of a torque driver to tighten right.
